# Installing IIS using Azure Management Libraries and DSC extension handler

Tags: azure, iis, azure-sdk-.net

I'm looking at the the new Azure Management Libraries example and specifically the example creating a VMSS with Linux and Apache [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/Fluent/Samples/ResourceManagement/Compute/ManageVirtualMachineScaleSetAsync/Program.cs#L209).

I wonder what would be the alternative to create a Windows Server 2016 VMSS with IIS? Assuming the DSC script is at hand, like the one referenced by [Windows VMSS and Desired State Configuration with Azure Resource Manager templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/extensions-dsc-template).

Maybe there is a way (I have not found) a Window Server (2016 Core) image with IIS to somehow use an ARM template for this part?

<edit: It appears if the Windows Core 2016 images either are recent

1. [Very recent](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/azure-stack/azure-stack-add-default-image.md) or
2. [Perhaps available](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/216369-azure-marketplace/suggestions/16700068-why-is-2016-server-core-not-on-offered-on-the-mark).

Either way it looks like at least there isn't an image with (and nothing but) IIS preinstalled.

Comment: I suggest you could create a Windows Server 2016 and install IIS on it, then you could generalize your VM and use the VHD to create your VMSS. Now, in your VMSS VM, IIS has been installed.

Comment: I lost a notification from your comment, I see. I suppose this is the most performant and secure way. Maybe another one could be using a standard image and the using the Azure Management Libraries to connect and install IIS.